# How to get count of "user id" in "referral column"

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `Users` and I have a column `id` and `referral_id`. The `referral_id` has the user id of the user that referred the person.

What query can do the trick, to see how many users an user has referred?

Right now, I have something like this, but it only gets 1 result.

`` SELECT id, username, count(*) FROM `users` AS referring
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `users` AS referral WHERE referring.id = referral.referral_id) ``

Comment: Update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: For a particular user or all users?

Answer (score 1):

For a particular user:

```
select count(*)
from users
where referral_id = ?
```

For all users:

```
select referral_id, count(*)
from users
group by referral_id
```

Comment: Well, almost.. I need to group the users who have referred more than 0 users. And then I want to know how many they have referred.

Comment: And if these users are in a specific user_level. In this case that would be user_level id 7.

Comment: @KevinS this query only returns users that have referred someone. In other words, `count` is never zero. You didn’t mention `user_level` in your question, so better to ask a new question about that.